# Sourcing bash scripts with argument parsing

Tags: bash, files

What happens when one sources a bash script that includes an argument parsing section?  I would like to execute functions without having to source the file.  But should I source the file, I do not want the argument parsing to get in the way.

Comment: If you `source` a file, it's just processed by your shell as if you'd typed it. If there are executable statements,  they'll be executed.

Comment: I have included same argument parsing in the file, which does not execute any of the functions if no arguments are supplied.